# Do it matters with different sampling methods in one survey?

Tags: sampling

I had changed my sampling method from convenience sampling to quota sampling during my study period. Does this cause any difference in my result interpretations?

My study is about the prespection of a new computer system used in a department where 70 workers. 15 items survey using a 5point likert scale is used.

I invited all 70 workers to complete the survey but only 18 replied. Then I personally target some of the workers who are for example: male or more experienced etc. Total respondent is 58.

The fact is I had all the demographic data of the 70 workers. The change of my sample method made my sample (58) more likely the popluation (70). Should I include this in my thesis and will the change make more biases when I interpreted the data?

Answer (score 0):

> My study is about the prespection of a new computer system used in a department where 70 workers. 15 items survey using a 5point likert scale is used.

This leads to no-response sampling bias.

> Then I personally target some of the workers who are for example: male or more experienced etc. Total respondent is 58.

I don't think this belongs to quota sampling because you don't stratify the sample into groups first and second, you don't sample the female and workers with less experience.

I would conclude that the bias would have been enlarged.